# Validity of the equation $dQ=CdT$ in different cases

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, reversibility

I know this question may be too simple so I apologise for that but nonetheless very necessary. In my class we have defined the heat as $$\delta Q=CdT$$ with $C$ the heat capacity, but I'm unsure if it works for non ideal gases too, I'm guessing they don't, but why then? I am sure that by writing definitions of the heat we don't have to worry about non ideal gases or ideal gases but now I'm quite unsure. Also I have a second question, is $\delta Q=CdT$ only valid for a reversible process? Because I have in my notes written so, but once again my teacher wrote it as a definition/axiom and we couldn't really understand **why** it wouldn't work for an irreversible process. Maybe is it because in an irreversible process the heat can depend on other stuff also? I'm not too sure so I wanted to clarify myself here

Comment: That equation is essentially the *definition* of the heat capacity $C$ (which is a function of the path through the state space) for a substance.

Comment: @Buzz I know but is it valid for all the irreversible process? And also is it valid for a non ideal gas?

Comment: It is always valid, because heat capacity is <b>defined</b> in that way. $C=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial t}$

Comment: @Qwerty Please write your answers as answers, not comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my class we have defined the heat as $$\delta Q=CdT$$ with $C$ the
> heat capacity

That is not the definition of heat. Heat is energy transfer due solely to temperature difference. Your equation describes the specific relationship between the change in temperature of a substance due to the transfer of energy in the form of heat where $C$ is the heat capacity of the substance. It does not "define" heat.

> ...but I'm unsure if it works for non ideal gases too,

If works for non ideal gases, but $C$ depends on the process. For a constant volume process $C=C_{V}$ where $C_V$ is the heat capacity for a constant volume process and $C=C_P$ where $C_P$ is the heat capacity for a constant pressure process. Moreover, as already pointed out, $C_P$ and $C_V$ are not defined in terms of heat transfer. They are defined in terms of the properties enthalpy and internal energy, respectively.

> Also I have a second question, is $\delta Q=CdT$ only valid for a
> reversible process?

No. It is valid for both reversible and irreversible processes.

> Because I have in my notes written so, but once again my teacher wrote
> it as a definition/axiom and we couldn't really understand why it
> wouldn't work for an irreversible process. Maybe is it because in an
> irreversible process the heat can depend on other stuff also?

It appears your teacher is wrong, or you misunderstood your teacher. Energy transfer in the form of heat is the same for a reversible or irreversible process.  What is different is an irreversible transfer of heat generates entropy whereas a reversible transfer of heat does not. The generation of entropy is covered by the second law. Conservation of energy is covered by the first law.

*Bottom line: The amount of the heat transfer to the system does not depend on **how** the heat is transferred between the system and its surroundings. It only depends on the change in temperature of the system.*

Hope this helps.

Comment: In the second paragraph about the question of if it works on non-ideal gases, did you meant to write "non-ideal" instead of "ideal gases"? Or else I don't know where you answer my question about if it works for non ideal gases

Comment: @Ulshy yes I meant non ideal gases. Sorry will fix. It applies to all gases as the specific heats are defined in terms of the properties enthalpy and internal energy

Comment: @Ulshy But the equation Cp - Cv = R only applies to ideal gases because it is based on the equation of state for an ideal gas only

Answer (score 3):

The heat in a process is dependent on process path while the heat capacity is supposed to be a state function, independent of path.  So defining heat capacity in terms of heat is incongruous.

To correct this deficiency taught in earlier physics courses, we define in Thermodynamics heat capacity, not in terms of heat, but in terms of state functions internal energy U and enthalpy H:  $$nC_v=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V$$and$$nC_p=\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_P$$ where $C_v$ is the heat capacity at constant volume and $C_p$ is the heat capacity at constant pressure.

Comment: This is your first answer, with which I do not fully agree. In particular, in the case of $C_v$, it is quite clear that the definition in terms of heat coincides with that of the derivative of the internal energy wrt temperature. Indeed, at constant volume, there is no work. Moreover, at the limit of vanishing difference of temperature, entropy production goes to zero and $nC_v= T\left.\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right|_V= \left.\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right|_V$

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90. I stand by what I said.  Moreover, for an ideal gas, even if V is not constant, $dU=nC_vdT$.

Answer (score 1):

When the system is a homogeneous substance of constant composition, the phase rule indicates that fixing the values of two intensive properties establishes its state. The molar or specific internal energy of a substance may therefore be expressed as a function of two other state variables. The key thermodynamic variable is temperature. With molar or specific vol- ume chosen arbitrarily, we have U = U(T, V) Then
$$dU =(\frac {\partial U }{\partial T} )_V dT+(\frac {\partial U }{\partial V} )_T dV$$

$$dU =C_V dT+(\frac {\partial U }{\partial V} )_T dV$$

The final term is zero in two circumstances:

• For any closed-system constant-volume process.

• Whenever the internal energy is independent of volume, as for the ideal-gas state and the incompressible liquid.

In either case, $$dU = C_{V}dT$$
$$\Delta U=\int_{T_{1}}^{T_{2}} {C_{V}} \,dT$$
Although real liquids are to some degree compressible, far below their critical temperature they can often be treated as incompressible fluids. The ideal-gas state is also of interest, because actual gases at low pressures approach ideality. The only possible mechanically reversible constant-volume process is simple heating (stirring work is inherently irreversible), for which $$Q = \Delta U$$ and Equation written for a unit mass or a mole becomes:
$$\Delta Q=\Delta U=\int_{T_{1}}^{T_{2}} {C_{V}} \,dT$$

$$C_v = (\frac{\partial{U}}{\partial{T}})_v $$
$$dU = C_{V}*dT$$

$$\Delta U=\int_{T_{1}}^{T_{2}} {C_{V}} \,dT$$

$$\Delta Q=\Delta U=\int_{T_{1}}^{T_{2}} {C_{V}} \,dT$$

If the volume varies during the process but returns at the end of the process to its ini- tial value, the process cannot rightly be called one of constant volume, even though $$V_{2} = V_{1}$$ and $$\Delta V = 0 $$However, changes in state functions are fixed by the initial and final conditions,independent of path, and may therefore be calculated by equations for a truly constant-volume process regardless of the actual process. Equation $$\Delta U=\int_{T_{1}}^{T_{2}} {C_{V}} \,dT$$ **therefore has general validity**, because U, Cv, T, and V are all state functions. On the other hand, Q and W depend on path. Thus, $$\Delta Q=\Delta U=\int_{T_{1}}^{T_{2}} {C_{V}} \,dT$$ is a valid expression for Q.
, and W is in general zero, only for a constant- volume process. This is the reason for emphasizing the distinction between state functions and path-dependent quantities such as Q and W. The principle that state functions are path- and process-independent is an essential concept in thermodynamics.

References:
(i) Introduction to Chemical engineering thermodynamics JM Smith, HC Van Ness, MV abbott, MT Swihart Eight Edition.